# ELMAH Logs Retention

Tags: .net-core, elmah

I am working with error logging using ELMAH and I succeeded plugging ELMAH in our application in local. I have followed the steps mentioned here [Logging Error Details with ELMAH (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs). I have some inquiries regarding that.

- I would like to ask the retention of the logs if we push that in higher environment.
- Since ELMAH is an open-source error logging library, what data or information are being sent to the ELMAH creator?
- Can we modify the columns in ELMAH such as adding another column?

Answer (score 1):

**I would like to ask the retention of the logs if we push that in higher environment.**

There is no retention on ELMAH error logs out of the box. Depending on where you store your errors, you will need to set up retention manually. In the case of SQL Server, you could set up a scheduled job that deletes rows older than x days, months, or what ever you prefer.

**Since ELMAH is an open-source error logging library, what data or information are being sent to the ELMAH creator?**

No data is being shared with the ELMAH maintainers. You host everything yourself why you would not share it with anyone else unless you explicitly open up your data for others to look through.

**Can we modify the columns in ELMAH such as adding another column?**

There's currently no way to log dynamic data as part of ELMAH. If you want to extend the error log with custom columns you will need to fork ELMAH and create this yourself.